# Linq to Entities Count subquery

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

Okay so I've got a bunch of places which users can rate (give a score). When fetching places I also want to know how many of my friends rated that place. Users become friends by sending requests.

```
FRIENDREQID -- ID of user that sent the request.
FRIENDRESPID -- ID of user that got the request
STATUS -- Status of the request. (Accepted / Pending)
```

This query does the job.

```
select 
    p.*,
    (
        select 
            count(*) 
        from 
            UserRatings ur, 
            Friends f 
        where 
            ur.PlaceId = p.PlaceId
            and (ur.UserId = f.FriendReqId and f.FriendRespId = @myUserId ) 
            or  (ur.UserId = f.FriendRespId and f.FriendReqId = @myUserId ) 
            and f.Status = 'A' 
    ) as FriendCount
from 
    Places p
```

I really struggled with coming up with a mutual query in linq to entities (I'm a beginner) and came up with this.

```
 var result = (from p in db.Places
                 select new PlaceDTO
                 {
                     PlaceId = p.PlaceId,
                     FriendRatingCount = (from f in db.Friends
                                          from ur in db.UserRatings
                                          where ur.PlaceId == p.PlaceId && 
                                                (ur.UserId == f.FriendReqId && f.FriendRespId == argUserId) ||
                                                (ur.UserId == f.FriendRespId && f.FriendReqId == argUserId) &&
                                                f.Status == "A" 
                                          select f).Count()
                 })
```

Is it my friend system model that makes this query a bit bulky? Anyone has any tip of approvements that can be done too make it more efficient, easily read?

Answer (score 0):

One question - why are you recalculating friends for every query?  You can figure out the friends, and put reference to them in the User object.  It's much simpler to do

```
var friendPlaces = users.Friends.Reviews.Where(r => r.PlaceId == placeID);
```

or even better

```
var friendPlace= users.Friends.Select(GetPlacesReviewed).Where(p => p.Id == placeID);
```

than have every part of the application know about your basic DB structure.  What happens when you have to change your schema in 2 months?

Comment: Could you explain this some more? Having a hard time with lambda. I cannot access Users.Friends as you do.

Comment: You need to write the users class with the Friends property.  It doesn't exist already.

Comment: But user class is generated from my sql server?

Comment: You can either extend that class, or make your own user class that talks to the SQL server generated class.  Having your business logic totally depend on your SQL server structure isn't a good practice, and is a typical ORM anti-pattern.